# Impala single insert statement creating multiple files

Tags: java, hadoop, spring-jdbc, impala

I have an `Impala` managed table and I am trying to execute a single statement insert query in `Impala` using `JDBC` connection.

Sample query -

> insert into employee (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (1, 'Ramesh',
>   32, 'Mumbai', 20000 )

But after successful execution of the query, I am getting multiple files instead of single file.

```
String query = "insert into employee (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (1, 'Ramesh', 32, 'Mumbai', 20000 )";
template.execute(query); //template is JDBCTemplate
```

I found some solution like `SET NUM_NODES=1`, I have tried using below query but the query is not working -

```
String query = "SET NUM_NODES=1; insert into employee (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (1, 'Ramesh', 32, 'Mumbai', 20000 )";
template.execute(query); //template is JDBCTemplate
```

Please let me know, how to use `SET NUM_NODES=1` and if there any other way available to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using below code -

```
template.execute("SET NUM_NODES = 1"); //template is JDBCTemplate

String query = "insert into employee (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES (1, 'Ramesh', 32, 'Mumbai', 20000 )";

template.execute(query); //template is JDBCTemplate

template.execute("SET NUM_NODES = 0"); //template is JDBCTemplate
```